# Yii - could not open input file yiic for Yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii, xampp

So I downloaded a yii archive then extracted it into my xampp htdocs folder.
I wanted to create a new app but tutorials show to use yiic when creating new webapps. The problem is no yiic is found, and even in the directory, I do not see any yiic file to execute the program.

Should there be a yiic.bat?
I download Yii version 2.0 for the latest framework.
I also tried creating via Yii version 1.6 and the command worked.
The problem is i cant find yiic on 2.0.

Comment: please check whether PHP environment variable is set or not? type "php -v" in command prompt it will give appropriate php version name if not add environment variable for php

Answer (score 5):

Please run init command after installing YII from composer 
`sudo php init`

It will ask for setting the environment, for beginning select "Development"